# safety of setObject and null

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

[PreparedStatement.setObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)'s  Javadoc says it's not safe to just pass null value, and recommends using setNull instead, which requires to pass the column DB type along.

Since it's not trivial to tell type of a null value in Java, I wonder if there's any resource listing the safety of calling setObject with null value for popular databases?

Answer (score -1):

There is a rather interesting page on oracle's java docs.

[~is interesting page :)~](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#table1)

Abhinav

EDITED as per EJP's comments:

Following declaration of setObject is better and recommended as per Java docs:

[void setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int targetSqlType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29)

*Note: Not all databases allow for a non-typed Null to be sent to the backend. For maximum portability, the setNull or the setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int sqlType) method should be used instead of setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x).*

Object type can be identified using mapping list, linked above.

Comment: Links to pages, whether interesting or otherwise, are not themselves answers. This one is completely uninteresting as the word 'null' doesn't even appear. -1

Comment: I would say the page is very interesting but is not related to the question. Also I failed to find these tables for Java 7, does it mean they are obsolete?

Comment: It did not see Java 7 in the question so I posted one that I had in favorites. All this applicable to Java 7 as well. Updated second link with latest one.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question. Your edit just consists of restating the problem. The question is about 'any resource listing the safety of calling setObject with null value for popular databases', i.e. a table showing for which databases setObject() with a null will work. You have not answered it.